# Single object json parse - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, nsdictionary

This has got to be something obvious that I am doing wrong.  I have been banging my head against a wall trying to figure out what is going on.  I already have this json parsing done in the android version of my app, now trying to parse this simple json in xcode and can't get it done.

```
NSError *myError = nil;
NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:kNilOptions error:&myError];  
NSLog([res objectForKey:@"Date"]);
```

This code get me the "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error.

Here is the json data and you can see Date is one of the objects:

```
[{"Date":"2016-06-17T22:56:33.0811255-05:00"}]
```

Thanks in advance for any help on this issue.  I've tried to simplify this post, but if more info is needed I will try and quickly provide.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5fsT.png

Comment: I was having a conversation with @Fogmeister but when I added the image the conversation history disappeared.

Comment: Please show the exception message. Unrecognised selector means you have called a mood on an object but that method doesn't exist. The exception message will show which object and which method.

Comment: The image attached is for the object res.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c1a25c0'

Comment: Is that what you were asking for?

Comment: Yes that indicates that your JSON's outer object is an array, not a dictionary - this is I'd I ate by the outer [ ] in your JSON. The dictionary is element 0 of this array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSONObjectWithData` is returning an array of dictionaries and not a dictionary. Your print out of the raw JSON confirms this:

`[{"Date":"2016-06-17T22:56:33.0811255-05:00"}] // This is an array`

However you're attempting to treat that response object like a dictionary. In doing so you're calling a dictionary method (`objectForKey:`) on an array. This results in a crash. Try something like this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
id responseObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];  

if (error) 
{
    // Handle error

    return;
}

NSLog(@"%@", responseObject); 

if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) 
{
    NSArray *responseArray = (NSArray *)responseObject;
    for (id item in responseArray)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", item); 

        if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
        {
            NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *)item;
            NSString *dateString = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Date"];
            NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
        }
    }
}
else 
{
    // responseObject is not an array...
}
```

Comment: So you are saying the my res object is really an array of dictionaries?  How can I then reference the first dictionary in the array then?  I've played around with diff versions of res[0] and res[0][@"Data"] but nothing is working.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm saying. I will post a little more code in a sec.

Comment: I get the following error on NSLog(firstItem);   -- Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary _fastCStringContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: I put in a breakpoint on the firstitem initialization and I get the same values of responseObject[0] as the res image above.

Comment: I modified the code, throw some additional log statements in there and (1) confirm you are getting an array and not a dictionary, then (2) confirm your array is not empty before accessing the first item.

Comment: I got the "unrecognized selector" on the NSLog(responseObject).  Commented that line out and then I get the same error on the NSLog(item) line.

Comment: HOLY CRAP!  I commented both lines out and then the NSLog(dateString) logged my json data row!!!!!  Whoo Hooo1!!

Comment: Try replacing those with NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);

Comment: I tried to upvote this answer but it won't let me cause I'm too new.

Comment: I just did it for ya. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is because you should first set res as `[NSDictionary]`. Then pick the first element in that array and then get `objectForKey: "Date"`. Normal JSON Data starts with a `{`, this starts with a `[`. Which means it's an array.

You can see it for yourself in the screenshot when it says @: 1 Element . THEN it says 1 key/value pair. The NSDictionary is inside an array.NSError

Try this code:

```
*myError = nil;
[NSDictionary] *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:kNilOptions error:&myError];

if (res.count > 0) {   
NSLog([res[0] objectForKey:@"Date"]);
}
```

Comment: I'm trying diff things but the syntax is wrong.  can you give me an example of what you are saying?

Comment: I updated my answer with some code you should try. I haven't tried this in Objective-C as I only know Swift. But let me know how it works out.

Comment: I tried to res[0] but I get error : Expected method to read array element not found on object of type NSDictionary.

Comment: Hmm... sorry but this seems to be a syntax issue. Something I know nothing about. As a last resort, can you try setting res[0] as a variable and then calling object for key on that variable?

Comment: Thanks for all the help, but we figured it out in the answer above!  You guys rock!

Comment: Sure, till we meet again.